# Limit hammer.js to horizontal swipes

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js which seems to work great and does mention that I can limit horizontal and vertical direction but I can't seem to get it to disable vertical swipe. Basically I have an off canvas navigation that I'd like to use only horizontal swipe to reveal.

```
(function ($) {
    var $sw = $('#left-content');

    $sw.on('swipe', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#ns-tool-bar, #left-content').toggleClass('slide');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use event.direction

Something like

```
if(event.direction == 'right' || event.direction == 'left'){
    //do your stuff
}
```

should work

Comment: The answer is depricated. You should now use event.gesture.preventDefault()  (see my answer down below for detailed answer)

Answer (score 8):

I think Shelly's answer is dated. I believe the current API uses event.gesture.direction.

Comment: Correct, at the moment the [docs](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started) say:

>  Following properties are available in `event.gesture`.

> `direction`   {String}        the direction we are moving. matches `Hammer.DIRECTION_UP|DOWN|LEFT|RIGHT`

Answer (score 1):

You could probably also just register for `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events. See the [source code](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/src/gestures.js#L203).

Answer (score 1):

Binding merely swipeRight or swipeLeft works fine for iOS and (i believe) Android, but not IE.

Answer (score 0):

silent_shelly's answer is correct, though you can also put a lock on drag directions:

```
drag_block_horizontal: false
drag_block_vertical: false
```

Documentary can be found [here](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started) under section "Gesture options"

Answer (score 0):

I combined all the answers and added event.gesture.preventDefault() for a working example:

```
$sw.hammer({ drag_lock_to_axis: true }).on("swipe drag", function(event) {
    event.gesture.preventDefault();
    if (event.gesture.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT || event.gesture.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT)
        if(event.type == "swipe"){
            swipeAction(event);
        } else {
            dragAction(event);
        }
    }
});
```

I also caught the event type so you can add functionalities like jump a whole container width on swipe but of course you can leave this out.